# How to find services pointing to a specific pod

Tags: kubernetes

For troubleshooting purpose, I would like to find out if any existing service is pointing to the specific pod, or at least ReplicaSet/Deployment, that I am currently working on.

Is this possible with kubectl? If yes, how so?

Comment: could you please update status of question below answer resolve your issue ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way with **kubectl** to find out however you can get an idea of service and pod by filtering with the **label**

```
kubectl get pod -l app.kubernetes.io/instance=example-service

kubectl get svc -l app.kubernetes.io/instance=example-service
```

however, you can use tools like https://www.jaegertracing.io/ for tracing

Or **Kaili** dashboard with **istio** depends on your stack